# Rails - how to instantly get id of inserted row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

I use this logic in my app:
**controller**

> @current_user = User.find_or_create_from_oauth(auth_hash)

**user.rb**

```
  def self.find_or_create_from_oauth(auth_hash)
    provider = auth_hash["provider"]
    uid = auth_hash["uid"].to_s

    case provider      
       when 'twitter'
        if user = self.find_by_twitter_uid(uid)
          return user
        else
          return self.create_user_from_twitter(auth_hash)
        end

    end
  end

  def self.create_user_from_twitter(auth_hash)   
    a = self.create({
      :twitter_uid => auth_hash["uid"],
      :name => auth_hash["info"]["name"]
    })
    puts a.inspect
    user = User.find_by_twitter_uid(a.twitter_uid)
    puts '---'
    puts user.inspect
  end
```

Immediately after `self.create` I would need to run this line:

```
Assignment.create(:user_id => a.id, :role_id => 2)
```

The problem is, that the line `puts user.inspect` return something like this:

```
#<User id: nil, name: "...name...", twitter_uid: "96580821", provider: "twitter", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Why is in the hash returned **id: nil**?

Or, is there any other way, how to get the ID of last created record?

Comment: `puts a.inspect` above should already give you the id of newly inserted user record. I don't think you need to find the user by twitter_uid; you could use the 'a' object directly (as indeed you seem to be correctly doing in the `Assignment.create` line. Is this line not working?

Comment: The record probably isn't actually being saved. Ensure that the record being saved is in fact valid.

Comment: Andrew Marshall is probably right. I would change `a = self.create` to `a = self.create!` to throw an error if the creation is not successful.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has been correctly saved, you can use directly `a`:

```
a.assignments.create(:role_id => 2)
```

Otherwise (check using `create!` instead of `create`) there may be a validation error.